# How do I do a multi tier count breakdown using Aggregation in mongo DB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document of a following structure.

```js
{
  name: "John Doe",
  City : "OK",
  Prepaid: "Y"
},
{
  name: "Jane Doe",
  City : "CA",
  Prepaid: "N"
},
{
  name: "Jule Doe",
  City : "OK",
  Prepaid: "N"
},
{
  name: "Jake Doe",
  City : "OK",
  Prepaid: "Y"
}
```

I would like to group this first based on the city and then Prepaid and get individual counts of each prepaid types. Something that looks similar to this.

```js
{
  City : OK
  Count : {
    "filter": prepaid,
    "count": {
      Y : 2
      N: 1
    }
  }
}

{
  City : CA
  Count : {
    "filter": prepaid,
    "count": {
      Y : 0
      N: 1
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing aggregation based on multiple fields and it gives me the total count of the documents and not the breakdowns.

Here's what I tried for my aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:matchquery
    },{$group:{_id:{city: '$city', prepaid: '$prepaid' }, count:{$sum:1}
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) twice to count by `prepaid` first and then you can apply [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to get `Y/N` as object keys:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { city: "$City", prepaid: "$Prepaid" },
            total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $grop: {
            _id: "$_id.city",
            Count: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.prepaid", v: "$total"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            city: "$_id",
            Count: { $mergeObjects: [ { filter: "prepaid" }, { count: { $arrayToObject: "$Count" } } ] }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tJ02esf2YEv)

Comment: This helps so much. I have one more question, If I have those multiple group arguments ad-hoc, is there a way I could nest them all together?

Comment: @sajakupadhyaya I'm not sure if I understand, could you show any example?

Comment: So My use case is basically the user sends ad-hoc queries to the backend with filters of their choice. The document has more properties like Income, Rent, Ethnicity etc. So The user could send filters like Rent and ethnicity instead of  prepaid and city mentioned above.  So the code that has to send the aggregation query is not sure on what its getting as a grouping arguments.

Comment: @sajakupadhyaya I think it will be better to open another question and describe that with an example